# Font awesome icon not working as content in CSS

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I know there are many similar questions here in SO, but for some reason, the answers provided won't work for me.  I was to use [this](https://fontawesome.com/icons/exclamation-circle?style=solid) font awesome icon, but it won't show. When I try other icons, they work. I have been following [this documentation.](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements)

This is how it shows now:
[image]

```css
.input-validation-error input {
  border: 2px solid #f46262;
}

.input-validation-error input[type="text"] {
  position: relative;
}

.input-validation-error::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  content: "\f06a";
}
```

```html
<!-- FONT AWESOME -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form class="registration-form">
  <div class="form-group input-validation-error">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Nombre de usuario">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to set the `font-weight` property. You can try this and it should work now:

```
.input-validation-error::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    color: red;
    position: relative;
    content: "\f06a";
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You have any idea of why this? For this icon it have to be **font-weight > 600**, but there are other examples (or icons) where is not nedeed.

Comment: The `exclamation-circle` icon has a **Solid** style (the first link you posted shows that). In the second link you posted, the instructions mention the `font-weight` property "_Set the font-weight: 900 (Solid), 400 (Regular or Brands), 300 (Light)_".

Comment: Thanks, but was not me who posted que question, i just was making an answer too but did not post because can't figure out that thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "class" for fa-icons.

```
.....
<div class="form-group input-validation-error">
 <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle input-validation-error"></i>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Nombre de usuario">
</div>
.....
```